# Router is duplicating when clicking a <Link> element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying react router, and I've set up my routes:

```
var routes = (
  <Route name="app" handler={App}>
    <Route name="customers" path="api/customers" handler={UserBox}/>
    <Route name="login" path="login" handler={LoginBox}/>
 </Route>
);
```

In a a navbar I have put :

```
<ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li><Link to="login">Login</Link></li>
                      <li><Link to="customers">Customers</Link></li>
                    </ul>
```

On the surface everything seems to works fine, but when I look the console I found this:

`ReactMount: Root element has been removed from its original container. New container: null`

and my main route is duplicated:
[image]

My router code:

```
var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
  <Route name="customers" path="/api/customers" handler={UserBox}/>
  <Route name="login" path="/login" handler={LoginBox}/>
  </Route>
  );


$(document).ready(function () {
    Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Root) {
      React.render(<Root/>, document.body);
   });
});
```

Comment: If you include your router code we'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is likely that your action (or something else) is triggering a re-render at the same time that your `transitionTo` is triggering a re-render. Try this simple fix and see if it solves it:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  this.context.router.transitionTo('/api/customers')
}.bind(this), 0)
```

If that doesn't help, try rendering into a wrapper `<div>`, put your bootstrapping script at the bottom of your body, and remove the `$(document).ready` wrapper. It's always a good idea to render into a wrapper instead of the body in case other libs mutate `<body>` contents. And there are circumstances where the `ready` wrapper can call its callback when you don't want it to. Making these changes should at least put you in a more predictable situation.

Comment: I 've just find out that even if I simply click on <Link> element it happens the same, so the problem must be with the configuration... but can't figure out why

Comment: It sounds like your router is maybe rendering twice. Is that `Router.run` script possibly being called twice somehow? Try also just including your scripts at the bottom of your `<body>` and omit the `$(document).ready` wrapper.

Comment: I've put `<script type="text/jsx">
          Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Root) {
              console.log("render touring.................");
              React.render(<Root/>, document.body);
          });
    </script>` just before my `</body>` but it says: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: okay try putting a `<div id="router-wrapper">` at the top of your body and then render the router into `document.getElementById('router-wrapper')` instead of `document.body`.

Comment: same `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element` :(

Comment: Wait, I've tried to close immediately the tag (in the first trial there it was expecting a content inside) so it would render immediately, and it seems to work. It doesn't duplicate the router. I am testing and let you know

Comment: I confirm that it works! It has something to do with the fact that document ready fires again in the filecycle of the app apparently... if you write and answer and explain it I can give you the green tick! thank you